# Is it possible to disable individual cookies on a page level

Tags: cookies

Preface, I'm new here and already looked for the answer and couldn't find it. Not a tech guy, but slowly trying to learn so apologies if this seems like an asinine question.

I have a site that cookies members and displays them member only page and the noncookied side that displays as "prospect". I am running a campaign targeted at specific pages on the site but only on the prospect side. However, members should see it too and being a member already redirects to the member page thus avoiding the campaign all together as a member. There is no option to display the information in the member area as well, so is there a way to block the member cookie for these specific pages?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you just avoid redirecting if the URL equals the page you want to display to these members? It's a much better approach than trying to do something to the browser (where the cookies are stored).

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe so, if I understand your question. Cookies are per domain.